# tvOS + SwiftUI Focusing between sections

Tags: swiftui, tvos

I've set up a pretty simple SwiftUI tvOS app.  I'm having a hard time with the Focus engine.  When the app starts, it's focused on "Launch" which is understandable.  Swiping down, goes to the StackView.  Swiping left/right across the items works great.  Except I can't swipe back up to get to Launch, no matter where I try it.

The goal is swiping up should always go up to the Launch button (focusing on the cells changes the content above)

Am I doing something glaringly wrong here?  I'm under the impression I'm not doing anything special or complicated.  Thanks

[image]

Here's my code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = EnvironmentsViewModel()
    @State private var currentEnvironment: Environment?
    var environments: [Environment]?

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack(spacing: 50) {
                BannerView(environment: currentEnvironment)
                    .frame(height: geometry.size.height * 0.6)
                    .clipped()

                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                    HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 50) {
                        ForEach(environments ?? viewModel.environments) { environment in
                            Button(action: {
                                currentEnvironment = environment
                            }) {
                                EnvironmentCard(title: environment.title, subtitle: "Coming Soon", image: environment.image, isFocused: environment.title == currentEnvironment?.title)
                                    .frame(width: 500, height: geometry.size.height * 0.4)
                                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                            }
                            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding(.leading, 50)
                .padding(.trailing, 50)
                .frame(height: geometry.size.height * 0.4)
            }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.top, .leading, .trailing])
            .onAppear {
                self.viewModel.fetch()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
struct BannerView: View {
    var environment: Environment?

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                if let environment = environment, let url = URL(string: environment.image) {
                    URLImage(url, placeholder: Image("Placeholder")) { proxy in
                        proxy.image
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    }
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                        .frame(height: geometry.size.height)
                } else {
                    Color.darkGray.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                }

                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                    Spacer()
                    Text(environment?.title ?? "Title")
                    Text("Description")
                    Button("Launch", action: {})
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                .padding(.leading, 50).padding(.bottom, 50)
            }
            .frame(height: geometry.size.height)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your case you could add an transparent element on the left of your launch button. This element will reset the focus to the Launch button whenever he is taking the focus. 
Take a look at this video : https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/10042

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to declare each line or level of focus (each focusable) as a focus section

just add: `.focusSection()` to the end of the HStack view you want to be a "focusable" line

read more here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/focussection()

so in your code it should look like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = EnvironmentsViewModel()
    @State private var currentEnvironment: Environment?
    var environments: [Environment]?

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack(spacing: 50) {
                BannerView(environment: currentEnvironment)
                    .frame(height: geometry.size.height * 0.6)
                    .clipped()
                    .focusSection() // <-------- ADD THIS ############

                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                    HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 50) {
                        ForEach(environments ?? viewModel.environments) { environment in
                            Button(action: {
                                currentEnvironment = environment
                            }) {
                                EnvironmentCard(title: environment.title, subtitle: "Coming Soon", image: environment.image, isFocused: environment.title == currentEnvironment?.title)
                                    .frame(width: 500, height: geometry.size.height * 0.4)
                                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                            }
                            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding(.leading, 50)
                .padding(.trailing, 50)
                .frame(height: geometry.size.height * 0.4)
                .focusSection() // <-------- ADD THIS ############
            }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.top, .leading, .trailing])
            .onAppear {
                self.viewModel.fetch()
            }
        }
    }
}
```